# Excel Moving Data From Rows Into a Column

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Sorry, I feel like this is probably super basic, but I am trying to use Excel and VBA to move data from multiple cells per row into an empty column in a specific order. Some of the cells might not have data so I have to check that as well and skip empty ones with something along the lines of `Value <> Empty`.

Basically, what I am trying to do is take a table that looks like this (with empty column A):

```
B1 C1 D1 E1
B2 C2 D2 [E2empty]
B3 C3 D3 E3
```

And set it up like this in column A:

```
B1
C1
D1
E1
B2
C2
D2
B3
C3
D3
E3
```

It would be entered in one row at a time into the new column.

I guess I am trying to figure out how to say the following in code

```
In Row 1, check if cell B is empty. If not, move Value to column A, first avaible cell, 
next cell in row 1, (repeat).
Next Row( do the same as row 1.)
```

So I was thinking of using `For i = 1 To rwcnt` where rwcnt is defined by  `CountA(Range("B:B"))`
To do the rows in order and then doing a similar thing inside that for-statement for cells (Maybe `j = B To E?`).

So my overall goal is to scan my range `(MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:E" & rwcnt))` and move everything into column A in the order described at the top, but I don't know how to move data to column A in sequence. Any advice on how to accomplish this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through all the used rows, looping columns starting at B in that row. Check if the cell is not empty. Write it to A next cell.

In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and selecte references.  Select "Microsoft scripting runtime"

```
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRowWrite as long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim fs As FileSystemObject

'Create the text file to write to
Set fs = New FileSystemObject
Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\test.txt", True, False)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
lRowWrite = 1
lRow = 1

'Loop through all the rows.
Do While lRow <=ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
    'Loop through all the columns
    lCol = 2
    Do While lCol <=ws.UsedRange.Columns.count
        'Check if it is empty
        If not isempty(ws.Cells(lRow, lCol)) Then
            'Not empty so write it to the text file
            ts.WriteLine ws.Cells(lRow, lCol)
        End If
        lCol = lCol + 1
    Loop

    lRow = lRow + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ts.Close: Set ts = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
```

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Comment: I tried this on a bit of a larger file (tens of thousands of lines) and it ended up crashing, do you know of a way to make it a little less intensive?

Comment: Take out the ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate.

Comment: It didn't spit out an error, but the screen followed the activate till about cell 980 then excel stopped responding. Trying without the activate command still ended up causing excel to stop responding after a while. It is definitely doing the process correctly, its just too intensive with this large of a file it seems.

Comment: Would outputing the data into a txt file work for you? It could then be imported back into excel if needed.

Comment: Yeah, that would probably be fine, I think it has to go to a .txt eventually anyway. So long as everything is on its own line, a data txt file should be good.

Comment: I made one more change. Let's see if that tames it. I added the Application.ScreenUpdating = False and Application.ScreenUpdating = True lines.  You will not see the data being written to column A until done if it finishes.  If not i'll change it to pause every once and a while.

Comment: I chagned it to write it out to a text file.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then another idea would be to add to text file and import to Excel. Also, @ScottT, when it doesn't respond, does Windows prompt you saying so, or again, does Excel just kind of fade out and sit there?

Comment: @MatthewD - does the `ts.WriteLine ws.Cells(lRow, lCol)` line write to a new line automatically? Or do you have to specify somewhere where a line break is?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes it does.

Comment: @Scott T  Note that i added some text above the code.  In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and selecte references. Select "Microsoft scripting runtime"

Comment: Yes, I am trying this right now, it worked on the abbreviated file and currently I have a wait-wheel while running it on the large file

Comment: We could put a counter in there that would tell you ever 100,000 or so lines what it has done. If needed.  You can watch the text file grow as well.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to working, It will likely just take a bit of time. Thanks for everything!

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long, k As Long, i As Long, colALastRow As Long
Dim rng           As Range
Dim ws            As Worksheet

'Columns(1).Clear   ' uncomment this if you want VB to force Col. A to be cleared
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count    'This will get the last column
lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count    'this will get the last used row

k = 2                        'Set k to 2, to start in Col B
colALastRow = 1              'This starts at 1, since your entire Column A is empty

With ws
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        lastCol = .Cells(i, 2).End(xlToRight).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, lastCol))
        ' rng.Select
        rng.Copy
        .Range(.Cells(colALastRow, 1), .Cells(colALastRow + (lastCol), 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        colALastRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1

    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox ("Done!")
End Sub
```

Edit: Changed the `lastCol`, `lastRow`, etc. from `Integer` to `Long`, since there will be over 32,767 rows.

Edit 2: I commented out `rng.Select`.  This is because there's no reason to select it for the Macro.  I only had it there, because as I worked through the macro (using F8), I wanted to make sure it was grabbing the right ranges.  It is, so you can comment this out.  It might even make it run slightly faster :)

Comment: Thank you, this will definitely be helpful in future scenarios, thanks for putting all the comments in there!

Comment: No worries, happy to help!

Comment: So I also tried this one on a larger file and it ended up crashing Excel. Do you know of a way to do this where it is less intensive? Would doing something without using select help?

Comment: What happened when it crashed? It may take some time to run depending on how large your spreadsheet is.  What's the last row and last column used in your spreadsheet?  Also, you can step through the macro with F8, and see where it gives you an error.

Comment: Yeah, it functioned fine on a test sheet of about 20 rows, but when using it on my ~50k row spreadsheet, it just sort of timed out and excel stopped responding.

Comment: Check my code, I updated it (I turned off screen refreshing, which should help speed it up, `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`).  Also, when you say Excel stopped responding, does it crash? Or does it kind of fade out, with the spinning circle / hourglass, showing it's working? With 50k + rows, it might take a minute or two.

Comment: It just says not responding, I guess it hasn't force closed itself yet. I'll force close and try changing the code if it isn't done in 5 or so minutes.

Comment: Hm - There's a possibility that your data will 'need' to go beyond the maximum amount of rows Excel allows.  If you just highlight your entire data range, how many cells are filled (what's the Count)?

Comment: About 1.05 million cells, so it shouldn't be ranging it

Comment: Excel tops out at 1.048576 million rows per sheet, so there's your problem.

Comment: Excel's max row is around 1048576 (depending on what version).  If you have more than that, you're going to exhaust the available cells.  Do you have to have them all in column A, Individually? Is there perhaps some other way to do it?  Also, change everything in the `Dim lastRow` line from `Integer` to `Long` to see if that helps.  But again, you can't have more than ~1.05M entries in a single column.

Comment: Kudos for using "Transpose" instead of cell-by-cell looping

Comment: Oh, my entire data range, I'm sorry, I thought you were asking my max. My max number of usable cells is about 1.05 million , I only have about 78k rows with 3 or 4 columns, so I shouldn't be out ranging excel.

Comment: @BruceWayne I like the range approach you took. I need to toy around with that some myself.

Comment: @MatthewD - thanks! It's pretty easy to use that way, especially when dealing with dynamic ranges.